# What is the rule of equating exponents called?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

For example:

$$2^{2n-1} = 2^{n+2}
\Rightarrow 2n - 1 - n - 2 = 0 \Rightarrow n = 3$$

I couldn't find this rule in properties of exponents i.e when the bases are equal, the exponents can be equated. What is this rule called?

Comment: Take the logarithm of both sides with respect to base  $2$...

Comment: @percusse, The OP asks for the **name** of the rule.

Comment: @DidierPiau That's correct. But I intended to give a hint, not the answer.

Comment: @DidierPiau: I think that as a comment that is fine - an answer might be "taking logarithms"

Comment: @percusse, sure, but a hint of what? Of a proof of the rule (which is not asked by the OP) or of the name of the rule? Well, anyway, this is no big deal.

Comment: @DidierPiau Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I will try to state explicitly if I want to give a hint next time.

Comment: In the specific case where the base and exponents are integers, this is (a corollary of) the unique-prime-factorization theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end, it comes down to the fact that the function
$$x\longmapsto 2^x$$
is "one-to-one"; that is, that different inputs yield different outputs. That is, that the graph of $y=2^x$ passes the so-called "horizontal line test": a horizontal line intersects the graph at most once.

It's the same reason that we can go from $a^3 = b^3$ to $a=b$: because the function $x\longmapsto x^3$ is one-to-one; and why we *cannot* go from $a^2=b^2$ to $a=b$: because $x\longmapsto x^2$ is *not* one-to-one (different inputs may give the same output; e.g., $(-1)^2 = 1^2$ even though $-1\neq 1$).

When a function is one-to-one, it has an *inverse*; and applying the inverse "undoes" what the original function does. That's what taking "logarithm base 2" is: the inverse of the exponential base 2.

Answer (score 2):

It's merely the fact that exponential functions whose base is a positive number other than 1 are one-to-one functions.  If $f$ is a one-to-one function and $f(2n-1) = f(n+2)$ then $2n-1=n+2$.

Answer (score -1):

If $f(x)$ is monotone (a slightly more restrictive condition than $1-1$ but satisfied by $f(x) = 2^x$) and $f(y) = f(x)$,  then $y = x$.

Most of the tables of "rules of exponents" I found were given names like "Rule 1" or "Rule 2", so I see the complaints about failing on giving a "name" somewhat arbitrary. If you wanted to use a "rule of exponents", then try combining the rule that might be called: "ratios imply subtraction of powers" and the "rule" that says if 2^x=1 that x=0 :

```
 a^m/a^n = a^(m-n) combined with the "rule" that if 2^m= 1 then m=0
```

You can then divide both sides 2n-1 and simplify.

Comment: You're not actually answer the question, but merely stating the property that the OP asks about.

Comment: Well, most "rules" are defined for purposes of simplification of expression.  This is more of a derivation of an implication, and would probably be given as the name of a "lemma" or "theorem". Did you also downvote the other two contributors?

Comment: I have not down voted anyone.